# Then once there

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the correct way of phrasing the sentence about double examination, i.e. the first examination upon transfer from a warehouse to the airport and the second one in the airport.

> Cargo is **twice subjected to** examination, once upon transfer to the airport and **then once there**?

How to avoid the repetition of the 'airport' in the sentence? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cargo is twice subjected to examination, once upon transfer to the airport and then **after arrival**.

Comment: I am not sure that the second examination is carried out immediately upon arrival. I would like to avoid that phrasing. Could you please suggest something else?

Comment: OK, check my edit.